# Ajax load data on dropdown select

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

There is a dropdown in my view. When I select an item in dropdown, ajax should load. So there is a table locations and it has one to many relation with contacts.

So when I select a location from locations dropdown, contact corresponding to that should load. But it is not happening.

controller:

```
public function location_contacts()
{
    $contacts = Contact::all();
    return view('partials.bookavisit_contact')->with(['contacts' => $contacts]);
}
```

location dropdown:

```
<div class="inline-control location-icon dropdown-icon">
    <select class="form-control" name="visit-location" id="visitLocation" onChange="getContact(value);" >
        <option date-person="lorem impsum" date-mail="lorem.ipsum@gmail.com" >Select Location</option>
        @foreach($locations as $location)
        <option date-person="lorem impsum" date-mail="lorem.ipsum@gmail.com" value="{!! $location->id !!}" >{!! $location->address !!}, {!! $location->city !!}, {!! $location->state !!}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

script:

```
@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getContact(val) {

        var ajaxUrl = "/location_contacts";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data:'location_id='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#contact").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
@endsection
```

partial view of contact:

```
<div id="location-contact-info">
    <div class="content-head" id="contact">
        <h5  class="wow fadeInUp">Lorem ipsum</h5>
    </div>
    @foreach($contacts as $contact)
    <div class="contact-info-group row">
        <div class="contact-label">Contact Person:
            <span id="location-contact-name">{{$contact->first_name}} {{$contact->last_name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-info-group row">
        <div class="contact-label">Email:
            <span id="location-contact-mail" ><a href="mailto:{{$contact->email}}">{{$contact->email}}</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Try `$("#contact").append(data);`

Comment: Tried it ! but nothing happened and no error on console

Comment: The parameter of getContact is val instead it should be this.options[this.selectedIndex]

Comment: Yeah done it! Not working.

Comment: Are you getting request on your PHP file?

Comment: Nope. Actually i don't know ajax.Using it first time. Do i need to get Request $request ?

Comment: I don't see `location_id` post data being get in the `location_contacts` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your **html**, your ID `contact` is in your partial and need's to be in your main view like this:

```
<div class="inline-control location-icon dropdown-icon">
    <select class="form-control" name="visit-location" id="visitLocation" onChange="getContact(value);" >
        <option date-person="lorem impsum" date-mail="lorem.ipsum@gmail.com" >Select Location</option>
        @foreach($locations as $location)
        <option date-person="lorem impsum" date-mail="lorem.ipsum@gmail.com" value="{!! $location->id !!}" >{!! $location->address !!}, {!! $location->city !!}, {!! $location->state !!}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

For that reason the `$("#contact").html(data);` doesn't work.

Try with that.

Regards